# How to sort orders based on orders meta value in Woocommerce / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress website and Woocommerce installed in it, Im displaying orders in admin along with the some extra values which im collecting from ordering page and storing them in other table related to eoocommerce.

We have sorting facility based on the columns which are common in WP post related tables, but I need to sort the query based on the field from other table.

How to achieve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to did more deeper and you certainly need some php knowledge to achieve this. In a project I had to develop something similar, I'm sharing the code but you need to edit as per your requirement.

```
// this action brings up a dropdown select box over the posts list in the dashboard
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','my_custom_restrict_manage_posts');

function my_custom_restrict_manage_posts() {

    if( current_user_can('manage_options') ){

        global $typenow;
        global $wp_query;
        global $woocommerce;

        if ($typenow=='shop_order') {

            // here you create your own selectbbox
            // you can enqueue js using wc_enqueue_js()

        }

    }
}

function my_custom_orders_by_query( $vars ) {
    global $typenow, $wp_query;

    // check your filter that might come form the previous dropdown
    if ( $typenow == 'shop_order' && isset( $_GET['select_box_name'] )  ) {

        $meta_key = ''; // your meta key

        $vars['meta_key'] = ''; // your meta value that came from the query string
        // you might want this because that will show in the url of the page

        $vars['meta_key'] = ''; // set meta key in the query var
        $vars['meta_value'] = '';       // set meta value in the query var
    }

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'request', 'my_custom_orders_by_query' );
```

This code is the most generic one. you need to customize how you want to setup a dropdown box in the header and how the key and value will reflect in the `request` filter.

If you require any more assistance feel free to comment.

Comment: you need to put this code in your plugin or your themes function.php file. By header I meant the section in the order list page over the order list table where all the filter parameters are placed.